# HTTP Restful application between 3 actors

Tags: rest

I am new at this argument and I hope not to ask something completely wrong. I'm developing an application which is composed by three actors: A,B,C.

A communicates with B using REST.
B communicates with C using REST.

A------>B------->C

A is a web MVC application

B is a generic web server implementing HTTP REST that memorize information and pass it from A to C and viceversa.

C is a server listening for requests.

I need to implement the HTTP REST on every actor (server part and client part) but, apart from the programming language, I have some problem understanding the logic of this three-actor-communication.

Which is the correct behaviour that A must have?
I'm explaining better with an example:

The general scenario is: A must asks C a book catalogue through HTTP GET request and the request is passing through B.

1. A is making HTTP GET to B and it replies with 200 OK (B cannot give the book catalogue because it does not have it.)

2. B is making an HTTP GET request to C and C replies with 200OK and in the body of the response there will be the book catalogue.

3. Now that B has the book catalogue, how can pass it to A? With a POST?

Is it correct the behaviour of all actors or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Provided the calls are fast enough, B may just keep A waiting while it talks with C and return the catalogue as the response of A's first call.

```
A ---> GET /books/ ---> B
|                       | ---> GET /books/ ---> C
|                       |                       |
|                       |<----- RESPONSE -------|
|<----- RESPONSE -------+
```

Answer (score 0):

From the excellent Wikipedia Article on REST.

A client cannot ordinarily tell whether it is connected directly to the end server, or to an intermediary along the way. Intermediary servers may improve system scalability by enabling load balancing and by providing shared caches. They may also enforce security policies.

From the standpoint of your client application A, there should be no difference between polling server B or polling server C directly. B is only acting as an intermediary. So B should not return a 200 response to A until B has forwarded A's request to C and gotten a 200 response.

The flow might look like this

```
A: GET(DomainOfB/someresource)
A: Wait for response from B
B: GET(DomainOfC/someresource)
B: Wait for response from C
C: Send response to B with 200 code if appropriate
B: Forward response from C to A.
```